# How to remove certain characters from a string using command prompt or batch file?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, command-line

My name is Syarz and I'm new to programming. I want to know how to remove characters from a string using cmd or batch file.

**This is the string in data.txt file:**

```
test.rar:$rar5$16$b19108e5cf6a5dadaa0ff515f59c6df7$15$f7f4933a2a8f7aa43d7fc31e86c47e2b$8$307ef2987e735bec
```

**I want this after running command or batch file in data.txt**

```
$rar5$16$b19108e5cf6a5dadaa0ff515f59c6df7$15$f7f4933a2a8f7aa43d7fc31e86c47e2b$8$307ef2987e735bec
```

**I have tried a few methods available on the website but none of them seemed to work for me. Either they delete entire string or delete the portion from where I don't want to.**

**What I have already tried**

1 -

```
more +1 "data.txt" > "data_NEW.txt"
```

2 -

```
@echo off
(
    for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("data.txt") do echo(%%L
) > "data_NEW.txt"
```

3-

```
@echo off
(
    for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "data.txt"') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
) > "data_NEW.txt"
```

4 -

```
@echo off
for /F %%C in ('find /C /V "" ^< "data.txt"') do set "COUNT=%%C"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        if %%I gtr 1 echo(!LINE!
    )
) < "data.txt" > "data_NEW.txt"
endlocal
```

5 -

```
void chopN(char *str, size_t n)
{
    assert(n != 0 && str != 0);
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (n > len)
        return;  // Or: n = len;
    memmove(str, str+n, len - n + 1);
}
```

6 -

```
void chopN(char *str, size_t n) {
  char *dest = str;

  // find beginning watching out for rump `str`
  while (*str && n--) {
    str++;
  }

  // Copy byte by byte
  while (*src) {
    *dest++ = *src++;
  }

  *dest = '\0';
}
```

7 -

```
for /f %%a in (input.txt) do set "line=%%a"
set "line=%line:pub:04:=%"
set "line=%line::=%"
echo %line%
```

8 -

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "first=true"
(for /f "eol=p delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  if defined first (set "line=!line:~2!" & set "first=")
  <nul set /p ".=!line::=!"
))>output.txt
```

**Just trying to learn something new.
Thanks, everyone.**

Comment: If you want _cmd or batch file_, why did you tag this `PowerShell`?

Comment: Nice password dump file btw... in Powershell:  gc data.txt | % { $_.Split(':')[1] }   <--- reads in all lines of the password dump file, splits the line by the colon and the 0th index will contain 'test.rar' in your example and the 1st index will contain the hashed password and outputs the data to the console.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (data.txt) do echo %%a` ?

Comment: Select-String -Path C:\src\t\sstext.txt -Pattern '(.*):(.*)' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value }

Comment: sls C:\src\t\sstext.txt -patt '(.*):(.*)'|%{$_.Matches.Groups[2].Value}

Comment: @Theo this is the first question I ever asked on StackOverflow and I kept adding the tags so that I could get the replies faster by the users around here but then I realize that I cannot add more than 5 tags so I started to delete the tags randomly. I hope it didn't offend you

Comment: @thepip3r I was expecting someone would love this dump file and here you are. Can you suggest me something that can remove the initial characters ( these guys test.rar:) from data.txt file rather than just printing the string in the PowerShell window?

Comment: @Stephan sorry but again the same question I need something that could remove the initial characters from data.txt file. I want to get rid of these guys here--> test.rar: but thanks anyway. It was informative and yeah It helped me to some point

Comment: @lit it gives an error message 'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you saying, my suggestion does *not* remove `test.rar:`?

Comment: @SyarzAsterisk - Are you running this in a PowerShell console?

Comment: @SyarzAsterisk, So I think I understand what you're after:  You want to remove the users from the file so that the only data left in data.txt are the hashed passwords, correct?  And most importantly as the others have asked, do you want a BATCH or POWERSHELL answer?

Comment: @Stephan it did work as you mentioned but the thing is I don't want to echo the string, I just want string in data.txt file without this guys--test.rar: either in original.txt or in New.txt. tried this too for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (data.txt) do echo %%a >> data1.txt)

Comment: @lit tried on both, cmd gave me the error which I have mentioned above, then I thought this might be PowerShell command but I got a different error in PowerShell console

Comment: @thepip3r Yes that's what I want. I would like to have a batch answer because I don't want to spend hours for the next step. I don't want to echo that so would be great if you could just give me an answer with no echo

Comment: @SyarzAsterisk, I gave you a PowerShell answer.  I'd contend that anything you can do in Batch can be done in PowerShell cleaner and potentially faster (albeit with more code)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (data.txt) do echo %%a >> data1.txt` should work (but adds an additional space to each line). Or `(for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (data.txt) do echo %%a) > data1.txt` to avoid that (and be much faster with large files)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks it worked using cmd as earlier I was not running cmd as administrator rights. Thanks to everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognize that you asked for batch but I haven't been providing a Batch answer so I'll the folks who were helping you with batch answer back.

Here's an easy way to do it PowerShell:

```
$f = Get-Content data.txt
$out = 'data2.txt'

$f | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Split(':')[1] 
} | Out-File $out -Append
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can I run this using batch file in PowerShell console? I meant how do I run these commands all at once in PowerShell?

Comment: @SyarzAsterisk, save it to a file myscript.ps1 and then execute with PowerShell:  powershell.exe -File path-to\myscript.ps1

Answer (score 0):

Well, many of your attempts – # 1 to # 4 – seem to remove the first line of the input text. # 7 and # 8 might come closer to what you want, but these approaches do not suit your sample data. And # 5 and # 6 are definitely not batch files.

To split text at a certain character, namely the colon in your situation, simply use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%I in (data.txt) do (
    echo 1st token: %%I
    echo 2nd token: %%J
)
```

In case the second part could contain colons on its own you want to keep, you need to change the token `2` to `*`, which means "all the rest":

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%I in (data.txt) do (
    echo 1st token: %%I
    echo remainder: %%J
)
```

Regard that a `for /F` loop combines multiple adjacent delimiters into one, hence a string like `abc::def` is going to be split into the parts `abc` and `def`. Also note that leading delimiters become removed, so a string like `:abc::def` is also going to be split into the parts `abc` and `def`. In other words, `for /F` does not return empty tokens.

Comment: As I am a novice in programming, I could not figure out what those codes mean to do on my own. Thanks for the help and thanks for the explanation.